# HighScore через SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Доброго времени суток. Помогите понять, что я делаю не так. Хочу сделать запись лучшего счёта. Но когда закрываю игру, данные не сохраняются. И так же как мне сделать так, чтобы при закрытии игры в другом классе (окне) тоже сохранялся лучший счёт. Заранее спасибо :)

```
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "file";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_NAME = "Score";
static SharedPreferences sharPre;
static int score2 = 0; // ЛУЧШИЙ СЧЁТ
```

// Game.iscore - это просто набранный счёт (подгружаю из класса Game)

```
@Override
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lose);


    sharPre = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);// копируй

    if(sharPre.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME)) { // проверяем есть ли в файле запись
        score2 = sharPre.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0); // Если запись есть, тогда загружаем из файла в переменную
    }
    else{
        score2 = 0; // если нету, присваиваем 0
    }


    if (Game.iscore > score2) { // если обычный счёт больше лучше счёта
        score2 = Game.iscore; // лучшему счёту присваиваем обычный

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharPre.edit();
        editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, score2); 
        editor.commit(); // эти 3 строчки записывают в файл значение переменной "score2"
    }
    else { // если счёт не больше лучшего
        if(sharPre.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME)) { // проверяем наличие в файле счёта
            score2 = sharPre.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0); // загружаем данные из файла в переменную score2
        }
        else{ // если нету ничего в файле, присваиваем 0
            score2 =0;
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onStop(){ // этот метод  записывает в файл данные при выходе из игры.
    super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharPre.edit();
        editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME,score2);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Пробовали вместо асинхронного `apply()` юзать `commit()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Сейчас попробую. А что насчёт последнего вопроса?

Comment: Последний вопрос я не понял.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну допустим у меня есть окно с проигрышем, там и показывается HighScore. А если я захожу в окно "Меню" и там закрываю игру, то всё сохранится?

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ commit не исправил ситуацию.

Comment: методы onPause и onStop точно будут вызваны. Сохранять лучше в onStop. И почему вы число сохраняете как строку? И как вы понимаете, что не сохраняется? В консоль выводите и там дефолтный 0?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вроде как всё понял, кроме одного. Если у меня счёт меньше, то нужно загружать из файла старое значение лучшего счёта.         '`else {
            if(sharPre.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME)) {
                score2 = sharPre.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, score2);
            }
            else{
                score2 =0;
            }
        }'` Я сделал  это так. Но приложение вылетает. `score2 = sharPre.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, score2);` Эта строчка не нравится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб для читаемости изменил сам код поста.

Comment: Вы поменяли тип на int, но читатет стринг. Возможно от этого ошибка, вы ведь не сообщаете какая в stackTrace

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не совсем понимаю как именно тогда мне поступить.

Comment: Вместо `score2 = Integer.parseInt(sharPre.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, ""));` напишите `score2 = sharPre.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, score2);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прошу прощения, тут забыл это изменить. Я это сделал, но вылетает всё так же.

Comment: Вылет всегда сопровождается описанием ошибки в консоли. Довавьте в вопрос её и строку на коей она возникает. Это обязательно делать при **любой** ошибке.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил вначале кода обозначение переменных и изменил код. Так же в коде указана строка, на которую ругается IDE.

Comment: "Ругается" значит не даёт запустить или вылетает при выполнении? Какая ошибка? NullPointer, IllegalState другая какая? Поменяв тип хранения очков со стринг на интежер вы очистили преференсы чтобы не пытаться в стринг инт писать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО. Не знаю даже как отблагодарить. Извиняюсь за то, что почти ничего не знаю по поводу того, что нужно чистить преференсы и т.д.

Comment: Заработало?.... Если да, то лучшей благодарностью будет описание решения проблемы в ответе.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, ответ написал. Ещё раз спасибо :)

Comment: Так же, вроде, надо и про commit вместо apply помянуть. При быстрой записи/считывании может рассинхрон произойти, т.к. apply асинхронный, в отличие от commit

Answer (score 1):

Код рабочий. Просто из-за того, что в файл сначала сохранялось String, а потом int, приложение вылетело. Я просто переименовал каждую переменную. Так что пользуйтесь. Надеюсь это поможет кому-то ещё и он не потратит столько времени на решение проблемы, который по сути нет.